# pandas df getting the value of a column associated with the max of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to groupby A, find the max of B, and for that max return the C associated with it.

```
import pandas as pd

a1 = [1,2,'x']
a2 = [1,3,'y']
a3 = [2,3,'y']
a4 = [2,4,'z']

df = pd.DataFrame([a1,a2,a3,a4], columns = ['A','B','C'])

groups = df.groupby('A')['B'].max()

df = df.join(groups, on='A', rsuffix = '_max')

df
```

result i get is

```
   A  B  C  B_max
0  1  2  x      3
1  1  3  y      3
2  2  3  y      4
3  2  4  z      4
```

result i want is

```
   A  B  C  B_max  C_max
0  1  2  x      3      y
1  1  3  y      3      y
2  2  3  y      4      z
3  2  4  z      4      z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here are a few options (no doubt there are more). (1) This one is just a wrinkle on what you're doing (it grabs the C_max column by using the `idxmax` of column B):

```
>>> foo = lambda x: pd.Series({'B_max':x.B.max(),'C_max':x.C[x.B.idxmax()]}) 
>>> print df.join(df.groupby('A').apply(foo),on='A')

  A  B  C  B_max C_max
0  1  2  x      3     y
1  1  3  y      3     y
2  2  3  y      4     z
3  2  4  z      4     z
```

(2) Or maybe this is cleaner:

```
>>> agg = df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: x.loc[x.B.idxmax(),:])
>>> print df.join(agg, on='A', rsuffix = '_max')

   A  B  C  B_max C_max
0  1  2  x      3     y
1  1  3  y      3     y
2  2  3  y      4     z
3  2  4  z      4     z
```

(3) Or you could do it all in a function that was called by the `groupby/apply`:

```
def foo(g):
    g['B_max'] = g.B.max()
    g['C_max'] = g.C[g.B.idxmax()]
    return g

print df.groupby('A').apply(foo)

   A  B  C  B_max C_max
0  1  2  x      3     y
1  1  3  y      3     y
2  2  3  y      4     z
3  2  4  z      4     z
```